# Unexpected behavior in waveforms

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, xilinx, counter

**Question:**
I was trying to make a counter that counts from 0 to 255 with different steps. For example this counter based on a control input could start counting from 0 with a step of +5. So we will have the sequence 0,5,10,15... In order to avoid overflow I used a signal called valid that will freeze the counter when we are on a state of overflow and in order to reset the counter I used a signal called RST that sets the counter on 0 so it can count again. The RST must be synchronous. The problem is that when I am changing the signal RST from 1 to 0 it seems that I need more than 1 clock circle. And I don't know why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. You can see my code below and the waveforms from simulation.

**My module**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--This library is used for numeral operations(+/-) 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

entity lab1 is
    Port ( Clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Control : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           Count : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Overflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Underflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Valid : out  STD_LOGIC);
end lab1;

architecture Behavioral of lab1 is

signal Qtemp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0):= "00000000" ;
signal overflow_temp:STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal underflow_temp:STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal Valid_temp: std_logic := '0';



begin
process

begin
    
    Valid<= Valid_temp;
    Count<= Qtemp;
    Overflow<= overflow_temp;
    Underflow <= underflow_temp;


 Wait Until Clk'Event and Clk='1';

        if RST= '1' then
                Valid_temp <= '1';
                overflow_temp<='0';
                underflow_temp<='0';

                Qtemp<="00000000";
                Count<="00000000";
                

          else
              if Valid_temp='0' then
                   Qtemp<=Qtemp;

            elsif Control = "000" then
                    if Qtemp < 5 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        underflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp - 5;
                    end if;

            elsif Control = "001" then
                    if Qtemp < 2 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        underflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp - 2;
                    end if;                 

            elsif Control = "010" then

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp; -- no need to check for overflow/underflow

            elsif Control = "011" then
                    if Qtemp > 254 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        overflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp + 1;
                    end if; 

            elsif Control = "100" then
                    if Qtemp > 253 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        overflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp + 2;
                    end if;

            elsif Control = "101" then 
                    if Qtemp > 250 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        overflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp + 5;
                    end if;

            elsif Control = "110" then
                    if Qtemp > 249 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        overflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp + 6;
                    end if; 

            else
                    if Qtemp > 243 then 
                        Valid_temp <= '0';
                        overflow_temp<='1';
                    else

                        Qtemp <= Qtemp + 12;
                    end if;

                end if;

        end if; 



end process;

end Behavioral;
```

**TestBench**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
 
ENTITY lab1_test IS
END lab1_test;
 
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF lab1_test IS 
 
    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 
    COMPONENT lab1
    PORT(
         Clk : IN  std_logic;
         RST : IN  std_logic;
         Control : IN  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
         Count : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         Overflow : OUT  std_logic;
         Underflow : OUT  std_logic;
         Valid : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;
    

   --Inputs
   signal Clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal RST : std_logic := '0';
   signal Control : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --Outputs
   signal Count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   signal Overflow : std_logic;
   signal Underflow : std_logic;
   signal Valid : std_logic;

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant Clk_period : time := 10 ns;
 
BEGIN
 
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: lab1 PORT MAP (
          Clk => Clk,
          RST => RST,
          Control => Control,
          Count => Count,
          Overflow => Overflow,
          Underflow => Underflow,
          Valid => Valid
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   Clk_process :process
   begin
        Clk <= '0';
        wait for Clk_period/2;
        Clk <= '1';
        wait for Clk_period/2;
   end process;
 

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
    RST <= '1'; 
    wait for Clk_period*10; -- hold reset for (at least) 10 cycles 
    
     
      Control <= "101"; -- control = 5 => count+ = 5 
        RST <= '0'; -- deactivate reset
      wait for Clk_period*54; -- 5(count step) * 52 = 260 > 255 so it overflows
      RST <= '1'; -- resets the state because of overflow
      wait for Clk_period*2;
      
      
   
      Control <= "010"; -- +0 Count = 0
        RST <= '0'; -- deactivate reset so it starts counting again
      wait for Clk_period*2;
    
      Control <= "011"; -- +1 Count = 1
      wait for Clk_period*2;

      Control <= "100"; -- +2 Count = 3 
      wait for Clk_period*2;
    
      Control <= "101"; -- +5 Count = 8
      wait for Clk_period*2;
    
      Control <= "110"; -- +6 Count = 14
      wait for Clk_period*2;
   
      Control <= "111"; -- +12 Count = 26
      wait for Clk_period*2;
    
      Control <= "000"; -- -5 Count = 21
      wait for Clk_period*2;
        
        RST <= '1'; -- resets the state because of overflow
      wait for Clk_period*2;
    
        
      Control <= "001"; -- -2 Count = 19
        RST <= '0';
      wait for Clk_period*11;-- 19 - 22 = -3 < 0, so it underflows
      --RST <= '1'; -- resets the state because of underflow
 
    wait;
  end process;

END;
```

**Waveforms**
[image: Waveforms]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's a problem of my computer/problem of Xilinx that there is a delay on some signals. I guess it's a problem of the software (Xilinx suite), because when I ran it on a lab's computer it was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your `RST` is apparently generated synchronously, too. As such, it becomes "1" in the same instant as the clock edge. Therefore, the `Count` (and other registers) will not read it (setup time violated in real hardware) and will reset with the following clock edge.

Add a little delay (like a "phase angle") to your testbench's generation of `RST`.

You can for example add a fraction of the clock cycle to the beginning of your process to generate `RST`:

```vhdl
    -- Stimulus process
    stim_proc: process
    begin
        -- This is added:
        wait for Clk_period / 4; -- add a little phase angle

        RST <= '1'; 
        wait for Clk_period * 10; -- hold reset for (at least) 10 cycles
        -- rest unmodified...
```

This will also help with the other input signals, which would give you similar headaches otherwise.

Comment: It seems that still there is a delay in my waveforms.Its  exactly one circle so i believe its a bug of xilinx.

Comment: Please edit your question and **add** the new stuff. If you added just the line I suggest, you can show it similarly as an excerpt (just in case my answer gets lost). But we need to see the resulting waveform to help you.

Comment: Post has been updated it.

Comment: Hm, you wrote an answer and accepted it. But I don't see the changed code and no waveform showing that the code change still needs an additional clock.

Comment: The delay that you said doesn't solve the problem on my computer.That's why i didn't changed the code.

Comment: That's why it is so important for us to see _how_ you changed to code, and what waveform results from the change. The chance that _you_ did an error is bigger than that the Xilinx suite has an error. 40+ years of experience: 99,9% of time I thought I found an error in other's software, it was my fault.